# How do I mock a superclass's __init__ create an attribute containing a mock object for a unit test?

Tags: python, mocking

I am attempting to write a unit test for a class's `__init__`:

```
def __init__(self, buildNum, configFile = "configfile.txt"):
        super(DevBuild, self).__init__(buildNum, configFile)

        if configFile == "configfile.txt":
            self.config.MakeDevBuild()
```

The config attribute is set by the super's `__init__`. I'm using [mock](http://mock.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html), and I want the config attribute to be a mock object. However, I haven't been able to figure out how to actually make that happen. Here's the best I could come up with for the test:

```
def test_init(self):
        with patch('DevBuild.super', create=True) as mock_super:
            mock_MakeDevBuild = MagicMock()
            mock_super.return_value.config.MakeDevBuild = mock_MakeDevBuild

            # Test with manual configuration
            self.testBuild = DevBuild("42", "devconfigfile.txt")
            self.assertFalse(mock_MakeDevBuild.called)

            # Test with automated configuration
            self.testBuild = DevBuild("42")
            mock_MakeDevBuild.assert_called_once_with()
```

However, this doesn't work--I get an error:

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/khagler/Projects/BuildClass/BuildClass/test_devBuild.py", line 17, in test_init
    self.testBuild = DevBuild("42")
  File "/Users/khagler/Projects/BuildClass/BuildClass/DevBuild.py", line 39, in __init__
    self.config.MakeDevBuild()
AttributeError: 'DevBuild' object has no attribute 'config'
```

Clearly I'm not setting the config attribute correctly, but I have no idea *where* exactly I should be setting it. Or for that matter, if what I want to do is even possible. Can anyone tell me what I need to do to make this work?

Comment: An observation: the return value of `super` is not an object that has a `config` attribute, but rather an object that has a method `__init__` that will add a `config` attribute to its argument.

Comment: Is that the entire `__init__`? If it is, it will only add self.config.MakeDevBuild if no configuration file name is passed, which you do in your test.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can't mock `__init__` by setting it directly - see [_unsupported_magics in mock.py](http://mock.googlecode.com/hg/mock.py).

As for what you can do, you can mock `__init__` by passing it to patch, like so:

```
mock_makeDevBuild = MagicMock()
def mock_init(self, buildNum, configFile):
    self.config = MagicMock()
    self.config.MakeDevBuild = mock_makeDevBuild

with patch('DevBuild.SuperDevBuild.__init__', new=mock_init):
    DevBuild("42")
    mock_makeDevBuild.assert_called_once_with()
```

where `SuperDevBuild` is a base class of DevBuild.

If you really want to mock `super()`, you can perhaps make a class and then bind `__init__` to object manually, like

```
mock_makeDevBuild = MagicMock()
def get_mock_super(tp, obj):
    class mock_super(object):
        @staticmethod
        def __init__(buildNum, configFile):
            obj.config = MagicMock()
            obj.config.MakeDevBuild = mock_makeDevBuild
    return mock_super
with patch('DevBuild.super', create=True, new=get_mock_super):
    DevBuild("42")
    mock_makeDevBuild.assert_called_once_with()
```

which works, but is quite ugly..

Comment: The link to unsupported_magics is broken, alas.

Answer (score 1):

I do it this way, mocking the inherited class init:

```
    from unittest import mock

    @mock.patch.object(HierarchicalConf, "__init__")
    def test_super_init(self, mock_super_init):
        # act
        ConfigurationService('my_args')

        # assert
        mock_super_init.assert_called_once_with(args)
```

Given the class:

```
class ConfigurationService(HierarchicalConf):
    def __init__(self, dag_name) -> None:
        """Wrapper of Hierarchical Conf."""
        # ... my code    
        super().__init__(args)
```

And if you want to also mock the ConfigurationService init, you can do quite the same:

```
    @mock.patch.object(ConfigurationService, "__init__")
    def test_init(self, mock_init):

        # act
        ConfigurationService('my_args')

        # assert
        mock_init.assert_called_once_with('my_args')
```

Comment: This solution does work, at least with Python 3. This answer contradicts the accepted one; the link provided in the other answer about unsupported magics is a dead link.